# How to convert not.camel.case to CamelCase in R

Tags: r, camelcasing

In R, I want to convert

```
t1 <- c('this.text', 'next.text')
"this.text" "next.text"
```

to

```
'ThisText' 'NextText'
```

I have tried

```
gsub('\\..', '', t1)
```

But this gives me

```
"thisext" "nextext"
```

as it does not replace the letter after the period.

Probably really easy but I can't work it out.

Comment: Please answer your question with an actual answer below, instead of editing it into your question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's one approach but with regex there's probably better ones:

```
t1 <- c('this.text', 'next.text')

camel <- function(x){ #function for camel case
    capit <- function(x) paste0(toupper(substring(x, 1, 1)), substring(x, 2, nchar(x)))
    sapply(strsplit(x, "\\."), function(x) paste(capit(x), collapse=""))
}

camel(t1)
```

This yields:

```
> camel(t1)
[1] "ThisText" "NextText"
```

**EDIT:**  *As a curiosity I microbenchmarked the 4 answers (TOM=original poster, TR=myself, JMS=jmsigner & SB=sebastion; commented on jmsigner's post) and found the non regex answers to be faster.  I would have assumed them slower.*

```
   expr     min      lq  median      uq      max
1 JMS() 183.801 188.000 197.796 201.762  349.409
2  SB()  93.767  97.965 101.697 104.963  147.881
3 TOM()  75.107  82.105  85.370  89.102 1539.917
4  TR()  70.442  76.507  79.772  83.037  139.484
```

[image]

Comment: Any recommendation on how to do the reverse (camel -> dot)?

Comment: I'd ask this as a new question posting a question in comments is not appropriate for SO.

Comment: Makes sense, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528625/how-to-convert-camelcase-to-not-camel-case-in-r

Answer (score 24):

Alternatively a regex based solution:

```
t1 <- c('this.text', 'next.text')

# capitalize first letter
t2 <- sub('^(\\w?)', '\\U\\1', t1, perl=T)

# remove points and capitalize following letter
gsub('\\.(\\w?)', '\\U\\1', t2, perl=T)
[1] "ThisText" "NextText"
```

## Edit: some explanations

`sub('^(\\w?)', '\\U\\1', t1, perl=T)`, `sub` is sufficient here because we are only interested in the first match. Then the first alphanumeric character is matched at the beginning of each string with `^(\\w?)`. The parenthesis are needed for back reference in the replacement part of the function. For the replacement `\\U` is used to capitalize everything that comes afterwards (which is the first character).

The same principle is applied in `gsub('\\.(\\w?)', '\\U\\1', t2, perl=T)` with the only difference that not the first character is matched, but every `.`.

Comment: Very nice approach.  I can usually figure it out in regex but it takes me some thinking.  Great work +1  May I request a small edit explaining a little bit about the magic of your regex for future searchers?

Comment: thanks for that, I added some explanations, hopefully this makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Alternatively, if you use lookahead assertions, you can do it in one line: `gsub("(?:(?=\\b)|\\.)([[:alpha:]])", "\\U\\1", t1, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: Actually, mine can be simplified further to not require the lookahead: `gsub("(?:\\b|\\.)([[:alpha:]])", "\\U\\1", t1, perl=TRUE)`. Sadly, @TylerRinker, the speed increase is negligible.

Answer (score 9):

Actually I think I just worked this out from the help file for toupper:

```
camel <- function(x) {     
     s <- strsplit(x, "\\.")[[1]]     
     paste(toupper(substring(s, 1,1)), substring(s, 2),           
     sep="", collapse="") 
 }    

camel(t1) 
sapply(t1,camel)  
this.text  next.text  
"ThisText" "NextText"
```

Comment: Hint: you might want to `Vectorize()` this function.

Answer (score 9):

`tocamel` from `rapportools` package does what you want:

```
> library(rapportools)
> example(tocamel)

tocaml> tocamel("foo.bar")
tocaml>     ## [1] "fooBar"
tocaml> 
tocaml>     tocamel("foo.bar", upper = TRUE)
tocaml>     ## [1] "FooBar"
tocaml> 
tocaml>     tocamel(c("foobar", "foo.bar", "camel_case", "a.b.c.d"))
tocaml>     ## [1] "foobar"    "fooBar"    "camelCase" "aBCD"
tocaml>
```

### Updated:

Another simply and fast solution (like @rengis):

```
camel2 <- function(x) {
    gsub("(^|[^[:alnum:]])([[:alnum:]])", "\\U\\2", x, perl = TRUE)
}
camel2(t1)
#> [1] "ThisText" "NextText"
```

Comparison with the @TylerRinker solution:

```
identical(camel(t1), camel2(t1))
#> [1] TRUE
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(camel(t1), camel2(t1))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>        expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval cld
#>   camel(t1) 76.378 79.6520 82.21509 81.5065 82.7095 151.867   100   b
#>  camel2(t1) 15.864 16.9425 19.76000 20.9690 21.9735  38.246   100  a
```

Comment: Funny how the function `tocamel` does not use camel-casing in its name

Answer (score 6):

Here another solution via the snakecase package:

```
install.packages("snakecase")
library(snakecase)

to_upper_camel_case(t1)
#> [1] "ThisText" "NextText"
```

Githublink: https://github.com/Tazinho/snakecase

Answer (score 6):

The `make_clean_names()` function in the  [janitor](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/janitor/vignettes/janitor.html) package has a function that can be used for this.

In your case:

```r
t1 <- c('this.text', 'next.text')
janitor::make_clean_names(t1, case = "big_camel")
#> [1] "ThisText" "NextText"
```

The parameter `case` can be one of many:

```
“snake”, “small_camel”, “big_camel”, “screaming_snake”, “parsed”, “mixed”, “lower_upper”, “upper_lower”, “swap”, “all_caps”, “lower_camel”, “upper_camel”, “internal_parsing”, “none”, “flip”, “sentence”, “random”, “title”
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>