# How to convert CamelCase to not.camel.case in R

Tags: r

In R, I'd like to convert

```
c("ThisText", "NextText")
```

to

```
c("this.text", "next.text")
```

This is the reverse of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672050/how-to-convert-not-camel-case-to-camelcase-in-r), and the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993721/how-to-convert-camelcase-to-camel-case) but with dots in R rather than underscores in PHP.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406974/splitting-camelcase-in-r

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not clear what the entire set of rules is here but we have assumed that

- we should lower case any upper case character after a lower case one and insert a dot between them and also
- lower case the first character of the string if succeeded by a lower case character.

To do this we can use perl regular expressions with `sub` and `gsub`:

```
# test data
camelCase <-  c("ThisText", "NextText", "DON'T_CHANGE")


s <- gsub("([a-z])([A-Z])", "\\1.\\L\\2", camelCase, perl = TRUE)
sub("^(.[a-z])", "\\L\\1", s, perl = TRUE) # make 1st char lower case
```

giving:

```
[1] "this.text"    "next.text"    "DON'T_CHANGE"
```

Answer (score 13):

You could do this also via the `snakecase` package:

```
install.packages("snakecase")
library(snakecase)

to_snake_case(c("ThisText", "NextText"), sep_out = ".")
# [1] "this.text" "next.text"
```

Github link to package: https://github.com/Tazinho/snakecase

Answer (score 4):

You can replace all capitals with themselves and a preceeding dot with `gsub`, change everything `tolower`, and the `substr` out the initial dot:

```
x <- c("ThisText", "NextText", "LongerCamelCaseText")

substr(tolower(gsub("([A-Z])","\\.\\1",x)),2,.Machine$integer.max)
[1] "this.text"              "next.text"              "longer.camel.case.text"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this fails for the `DON'T_CHANGE` input that Gabor's solution handles.  But it does handle the solution space requested by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Using stringr

```
x <- c("ThisText", "NextText")

str_replace_all(string = x,
                pattern = "(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z])",
                replacement = ".") %>%
    str_to_lower()

OR

x <- c("ThisText", "NextText")

str_to_lower(
    str_replace_all(string = x,
                    pattern = "(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z])",
                    replacement = ".")
)
```

Comment: What are the advantages of this over the accepted answer?

Comment: I suppose it is a personal preference, I like using the tidyverse packages which includes stringr.

Comment: Fair enough.  Personally, I don't like them:  they encourage practices which lead to bizarre obscure errors, e.g. the NSE that led to this mess:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/73722496/2554330 .