# How do I collect historical weather data from Wunderground using R function?

Tags: r, url, weather, collect, geturl

Can anyone help me fixing this code?
I used the script without issues last year, but now there is issues with the connection to the url.

How do I fix it?

What I want is to collect and arrange data from 2015-12-01 to 2016-04-15 from the weather station "EKAH" (Tirstrup, Aarhus Airport, Denmark).

```
    ############## 1) Run function --------------------

    wunder_station_daily <- function(station, date)
    {
      base_url <- 'https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport'

      # Example website: https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/EKAH/2016/06/09/DailyHistory.html?&MR=1

      # parse date
      m <- as.integer(format(date, '%m'))
      d <- as.integer(format(date, '%d'))
      y <- format(date, '%Y')

      # compose final url
      final_url <- paste(base_url,
                         '/', station,
                         '/', y,
                         '/', m, 
                         '/', d,
                         '/DailyHistory.html?&MR=1', sep='')

      # reading in as raw lines from the web server
      # contains <br> tags on every other line

      #   u <- url(final_url)
      #   the_data <- readLines(u)
      #   close(u)

      the_data <- getURL(final_url, ssl.verifypeer=0L, followlocation=1L)

      # only keep records with more than 5 rows of data
      if(length(the_data) > 5 )
      {
        # remove the first and last lines
        the_data <- the_data[-c(1, length(the_data))]

        # remove odd numbers starting from 3 --> end
        the_data <- the_data[-seq(3, length(the_data), by=2)]

        # extract header and cleanup
        the_header <- the_data[1]
        the_header <- make.names(strsplit(the_header, ',')[[1]])

        # convert to CSV, without header
        tC <- textConnection(paste(the_data, collapse='\n'))
        the_data <- read.csv(tC, as.is=TRUE, row.names=NULL, header=FALSE, skip=1)
        close(tC)

        # remove the last column, created by trailing comma
        the_data <- the_data[, -ncol(the_data)]

        # assign column names
        names(the_data) <- the_header

        # convert Time column into properly encoded date time
        the_data$Time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(the_data$Time, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

        # remove UTC and software type columns
        the_data$DateUTC.br. <- NULL
        the_data$SoftwareType <- NULL

        # sort and fix rownames
        the_data <- the_data[order(the_data$Time), ]
        row.names(the_data) <- 1:nrow(the_data)

        # done
        return(the_data)
      }
    }


    ############## 2) Get data for a range of dates ------------------------------


    date.range <- seq.Date(from=as.Date('2015-12-01'), to=as.Date('2015-12-04'), by='1 day')
    station <- 'EKAH'


    # pre-allocate list
    l <- vector(mode='list', length=length(date.range))

    # loop over dates, and fetch data
    for(i in seq_along(date.range))
    {
      print(paste0("Fetching data: ", date.range[i]))
      l[[i]] <- wunder_station_daily('EKAH', date.range[i])
    }

    # stack elements of list into DF, filling missing columns with NA
    d <- ldply(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

They changed the URL a bit and, while I think I could have just subbed out the bad URL for the new one, here's a modernized version of most of that code (I did 99% of the cleanup you did):

```
#' @param station station name
#' @param wx_date Date object or character string 
#' @param fmt if wx_date is not a Date object and the character string
#'        is not in "%Y-%m-%d" format, then specify the format here
#' @return data.frame of redings
get_wx <- function(station="EKAH", wx_date=Sys.Date(), fmt="%Y-%m-%d") {

  require(httr)
  require(readr)

  if (inherits(wx_date, "character")) {
    wx_date <- as.Date(wx_date, fmt)
  }

  wx_base_url <- "https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/%s/%s/DailyHistory.html"
  wx_url <- sprintf(wx_base_url, station, format(wx_date, "%Y/%m/%d"))

  res <- httr::GET(wx_url, query=list(MR=1, format=1))
  dat <- httr::content(res, as="text")

  dat <- gsub("<br />", "", dat)
  dat <- read.table(text=dat, sep=",", header=TRUE,
                    na.strings=c("-", "N/A", "NA"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  # saner column names

  cols <- colnames(dat)

  # via http://stackoverflow.com/a/22528880/1457051
  cols <- gsub("([a-z])([A-Z])", "\\1_\\L\\2", cols, perl=TRUE)
  cols <- sub("^(_[a-z])", "\\L\\1", cols, perl=TRUE)
  cols <- tolower(gsub("\\.", "_", cols))

  readr::type_convert(setNames(dat, cols)) # more robust than type.convert()

}

tdy <- get_wx()

str(tdy)
## 'data.frame': 36 obs. of  14 variables:
##  $ time_cest            : chr  "12:00 AM" "12:20 AM" "12:50 AM" "1:00 AM" ...
##  $ temperature_f        : num  51 50 48.2 47 46.4 44.6 44 44.6 44.6 44 ...
##  $ dew_point_f          : num  41 41 39.2 39 39.2 39.2 38 39.2 39.2 38 ...
##  $ humidity             : int  60 71 71 67 76 81 71 81 81 73 ...
##  $ sea_level_pressure_in: num  30.1 30.1 30.1 30.1 30.1 ...
##  $ visibility_mph       : num  28 6.2 6.2 28 6.2 6.2 7 6.2 6.2 28 ...
##  $ wind_direction       : chr  "WNW" "West" "West" "West" ...
##  $ wind_speed_mph       : chr  "2.3" "2.3" "2.3" "2.3" ...
##  $ gust_speed_mph       : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
##  $ precipitation_in     : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
##  $ events               : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
##  $ conditions           : chr  NA "Unknown" "Unknown" NA ...
##  $ wind_dir_degrees     : int  300 270 270 270 270 270 270 280 280 270 ...
##  $ date_utc             : POSIXct, format: "2016-06-08 22:00:00" "2016-06-08 22:20:00" ...

a_yr_ago <- get_wx(wx_date="2015-06-09")
```

You can add `""` to the `na.strings` vector if desired.

And, here's an alternate way to get readings for a range of dates into a `data.frame`:

```
library(purrr)

rng <- map_df(seq(as.Date("2015-12-01"), as.Date("2015-12-04"), "1 day"),
              function(x) { get_wx(wx_date=x) })
```