# pkgdown build_site example not rendering

Tags: r, pkgdown

I have the following as an example in two files

```r
@examples
x <- mtcars$mpg

some_func_here(x)
```

The `some_func_here(x)` is failing because it says that `x` is not found...

Here are the two pages where the example fails:
[bootstrap_p_augment](https://www.spsanderson.com/TidyDensity/reference/bootstrap_p_augment.html#ref-examples)
AND [bootstrap_p_vec](https://www.spsanderson.com/TidyDensity/reference/bootstrap_p_vec.html#ref-examples)

Here are examples where `x` the same `x` works [ci_hi](https://www.spsanderson.com/TidyDensity/reference/ci_hi.html#ref-examples)

So I am not understanding why it is failing, nor do I even know where to start looking.

Comment: This line:  https://github.com/spsanderson/TidyDensity/blob/a101d7568fbae0a883e7dfaf960236f98cb59fe8/R/vec-bootstrap-p.R#L34 refers to `x`, but there is no `x` argument or local variable in that function.  If you run in a regular session R might find a global variable named `x`, but `pkgdown` runs in a clean session.

Comment: For how to debug:  get the simplest case that fails.  (That would be your second example, which is very simple; if you only had the first one, simplify it until there's only one function call.)  Then look very closely at the code being run, to find out exactly where it is wrong.  Add `print()` statements if necessary to narrow that down, since you can't use regular debugging tricks in `pkgdown`.

Comment: What I don't understand is that literally `x` is defined as x <- mtcars$mpg but build_site() for some reason it fails to find it, some_func_here(x) uses `x` as the input. When I run the example in my session of RStudio and in a clean one it runs, so confused.

Comment: If you really care about that, then you could try debugging `build_site` to see how it runs your code, but if I were you I'd just fix the obvious bug in your own code.  You can make both versions fail equally by changing the name of `x` in the example code, e.g. `xnew <- mtcars$mpg; some_func_here(xnew)` will likely fail in any context.

Comment: I will try that, still weird as it works on other examples throughout the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, there is a bug in the `bootstrap_p_vec` function.  It has an argument `.x`, but it checked whether `x` was numeric.  See https://github.com/spsanderson/TidyDensity/blob/a101d7568fbae0a883e7dfaf960236f98cb59fe8/R/vec-bootstrap-p.R#L34 .

In functions in packages, the search order for variables is as follows:

- first look for local variables (including arguments) matching the name.  This would fail because of the typo.
- next look in the environment of the function, i.e. the package environment.  There is no `x` defined there so this also fails.
- next look through the imports declared for the package.  This also fails.
- next look in the base package, which is implicitly imported.  No `x` there.
- finally, go through the user's search list, starting with the global environment, and checking all attached packages.  Your bad code found the `x` in the global environment, so you didn't get the error you should have got in normal runs.

If you had named the global variable `xnew` and didn't have some other variable called `x` lying around, you would have got the error even in normal runs.

When `pkgdown::build_site()` runs your code, it doesn't follow the same rules.  It sets up a fake global environment, and never puts that in the search list.  Effectively this means it skips the last step above, so it never finds `x`.  In my opinion, this is a better way to do variable searches, because users sometimes have total junk in their global environment, and you don't want a typo to find that and work with it.  You want typos to cause immediate failures.

If you ran `R CMD check` on your package, you should have seen a warning that `bootstrap_p_vec` uses the global `x`.  Except you won't see that, because you have suppressed this warning by declaring `x` within `00_global_variables.R`, effectively saying that everything is okay (even though it wasn't).

Unfortunately, code in the tidyverse gets a huge number of false positive warnings about globals, so tidyverse code almost has no choice but to suppress this error.  They should have stuck with standard evaluation, and then you wouldn't have this insidious bug in your code.